# Exclude files from FileTree in Gradle

Tags: filter, directory, gradle, filetree

I want to exclude **src\main** and **src\test** files from **src**

```
FileCollection files = 
project.fileTree(/src/).minus(project.fileTree(/src\main/)).minus(project.fileTree(/src\test/))
```

How can I exclude this directories without double minus usage?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idiomatic way to exclude subdirectories from a `FileTree` is:

```
def files = fileTree("src").matching {
    exclude "main", "test" // relative to the file tree's root directory
}
```

PS: Instead of `.minus`, you can use `-`.

Comment: I was wandering can pass ArrayList ["src/main","src/test"]on FilerTree or something like that?

Comment: If you have multiple roots, you need to create multiple file trees and combine them with `+`. For users of a task or extension it can be more convenient if the task/extension accepts an `Object` (or `List<Object>`) representing the root directory(s), and converts to a FileTree internally. For API details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) (e.g. `Project#fileTree`) and the Javadoc/Groovydoc.